# How to solve the problem with "TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index"

Tags: python-3.7

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index.
I want to compare every elements of an array to zero and then give the maximum to a new array. When I run the program,it's spilt out a typeError in above, how to solve it ?

```
def prox_l1(v, lamda1):  # input v is a vector ,lamda1 is a scalar
    n = 512  # length of the signal
    v.reshape((n, 1))
    x = np.zeros((n, 1))
    for i in range(n):
        x[i] = np.max(0, v[i] - lamda1) - np.max(0, -v[i] - lamda1)
    # only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
    return x
```

Comment: Does the `v[i]` syntax work? That would be my guess as to why it's failing.

Comment: yes, it's can syntax work. Does the error means that the array is an non-integer scalar arrays? I dont know what the meaning of the error.